Automate console-conf on Custom Ubuntu core
i'm building a custom image for a RPI. When i build a pre-designed build from the RPI imager on boot it asks me to press enter to configure and i get to insert my Ubuntu one mail adres. When building a custom design this is not asked.
How can this task be automated? i mean it's good that it does not ask this when i use a custom image (because i do not want it to ask this as my devices have no keyboard and mouse attached) but this also means it's not configured, and my ssh key is not copied to the device.
Can the console-conf be automated?

"All pre-built testing images include console-conf, enabling those images to be configuration on first boot by connecting a device to a display and keyboard." you do need both.

I don't mind including this. But a way to automate this would be nice. i mean setting this in the yaml file at build would make things much better. I guess i can also insert the ssh key in the build image afterwards and go with it that way (and then remove console-config from my model yaml file.. I mean doing this manual for 1 device is great... but if you are facing 40 that are in different locations and some out of reach...... not a ideal solution...
